# DataView filter not working for rows imported in another DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

I am looping over 1 DataTable and looking up values from a 2nd DataTable using DataView.RowFilter and inserting values in a 3rd DataTable. For each iteration over DataTable 1, there may be multiple matching rows in 2nd DataTable, and sometimes the same rows in 2nd DataTable match again in another iteration over DataTable 1.

Before inserting values in the 3rd DataTable, I need to check if the value is already inserted in a previous loop iteration. If the row is not already inserted, I add the row in DataTable 3 using `dt3.ImportRow()`

My first RowFilter works properly to return the correct rows in DataTable 2, but my 2nd RowFilter to check against DataTable 3 always returns 0 rows, resulting in duplicate rows getting added.

```
DataView dv2 = new DataView(dt2);
dv2.RowStateFilter = DataViewRowState.CurrentRows;
```

Inside loop:

```
dv2.RowFilter = <some condition>;
dv2.RowStateFilter = DataViewRowState.CurrentRows;
```

Also tried with:

```
dv2.RowStateFilter = DataViewRowState.AddedRows;
```

What is wrong in the code?

EDIT 1:
If I construct a new DataView every time inside the loop, then the filter works correctly. Is there a way to refresh the DataView automatically when adding rows to the DataTable?

Comment: Lost in first paragraph. Share loop please.

Comment: If the datagridview is conneted to a datatable... datatable.AcceptChanges() should work.